# Installing Magento 1.4.1.1 on Mac OSX

Tags: install, magento-1.4

I am trying to install a new version of Magento 1.4.1.1 on a Mac with native Apache/MySQL

I am getting the following error

```
Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.
```

I seem to remember some solutions in the config.xml to change :

```
<pdo_mysql/>
```

to :

```
<pdo_mysql> 1 </pdo_mysql>
```

Unfortunately I don't have those lines in my config for this version.

I am just trying to install to compare tables to a newer version.

Comment: It only goes up to 1.7CE, but perhaps [this](http://www.magereverse.com/) will save you having to?

Comment: @JonathanHussey You rock! I forgot about that site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by commenting out lines 74-76

app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db.php

```
if (!isset($variables['have_innodb']) || $variables['have_innodb'] != 'YES') {
           Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('install')->__('Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.'));
       }
```

Magento 1.4.1.1 installed on my local system and I was able to get the DB structure and compare tables.

Answer (score 1):

You really should use a supported version of mySQL.  Most of the people at the agency I work at use MAMP http://www.mamp.info/en/ instead of native.

With that said, I never recommend modifying core files, but this solution was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443448/magento-complains-missing-innodb-when-it-is-available).

Line 59 of the file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php

Replace:

```
public function supportEngine()
    {
        $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
            ->fetchPairs('SHOW VARIABLES');
        return (!isset($variables['have_innodb']) || $variables['have_innodb'] != 'YES') ? false : true;
    }
```

with this:

```
public function supportEngine()
    {
        $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
            ->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
        return (isset($variables['InnoDB']) && $variables['InnoDB'] != 'NO');
    }
```

Comment: I already tried that solution, the file is not in 1.4.1.1